# Is there any possibility if the stage variable conversion is failed then capture the data into reject file

Tags: datastage

We have a stage variable using DateFromDaysSince(Date Column) in datastage transformer. Due to some invalid dates , datastage job is getting failed . We have source with oracle.

When we check the dates in table we didnt find any issue but while transformation is happening job is getting failed

```
 Error: Invalid Date [:000-01-01] used for date_from_days_since type conversion
```

Is there any possibility to capture those failure records into reject file and make the parallel job run successfull .. ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.

You can use the `IsValidDate` or `IsValidTimestamp` function to check that - check out the details [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZJPZ_9.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.parjob.dev.doc/topics/r_deeref_Type_Conversion_Functions.html)

These functions could be used in a Transformer condition to move rows not showing the expected type to move to a reject file (or peek).

When your data is retrieved from a database (as mentioned) the database ensures the datatype already - if the data is stored in the appropriate format. I suggest checking the retrieval method to avoid unnecessary checks or rejects. Different timestamp formats could be an issue.

Comment: Thanks Michael .. But when i use IsValidDate i am getting all dates as valid date.. When i use DateFromDaysSince job is getting failed .

Comment: Strip down the amount of data to identify the data producing the problem.